# How to introduce coefficient restrictions in a vector of autoregression VAR in python?

Tags: python, statsmodels, var

Can I request a bit of help with some problems I am having when including a simple restriction into a VAR?

I have the following VAR system of equations:

```
Y(t) = B(1)*Y(t-1)



Z(t) = C(1)*Y(t-1) + C(2)*Z(t-1)
```

Currently I am using this code:

`from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR`
`mod = VAR(data_test)`  
`res = mod.fit()`

This would give me results for a traditional VAR(1,1).
That is:

```
Y(t) = B(1)*Y(t-1) + B(2)*Z(t-1)

Z(t) = C(1)*Y(t-1) + C(2)*Z(t-1)
```

However I need to add B(2)=0 restriction in the estimation.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Currently I am using this code:

`from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR`
`mod = VAR(data_test)`  
`res = mod.fit()`

How can I add B(2)=0 restriction to this code?